USB port is slow, varies speed, but reliable
I have a HP NAS N36L. It has an internal USB and 4 external USB.
The external USB works as expected: If I connect a USB stick I can read and write at 12 MB/s.
Device       rkB/s     wkB/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sdi           2.50  12121.50    0.00    1.01  99.20
sdi           2.50  13399.50    0.00    1.02 100.40
sdi           2.50  12366.50    0.00    1.02  99.60
sdi           2.50  13529.00    0.00    1.00  99.20
sdi           2.50  13201.00    0.00    1.01 100.40
sdi           2.50  13441.00    0.00    1.01 100.00
sdi           2.50  13168.00    0.00    1.00  99.60
sdi           2.50  13564.00    0.00    1.00 100.00

If I move the same USB stick to the internal USB, the speed drops. One second it runs at 4 MB/s, then next it runs as 0.1 MB/s:
Device       rkB/s     wkB/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sdh           0.00    284.00    0.00    1.40 140.40
sdh           0.00    100.00    0.00    0.93  93.60
sdh           0.00    212.00    0.00    0.93  94.00
sdh           4.00   3912.00    0.00    0.43  50.40
sdh           4.00   1184.00    0.00    0.85  87.60
sdh           0.00     88.00    0.00    0.68  67.60
sdh           0.00    844.00    0.00    0.87  88.40
sdh           0.00    216.00    0.00    1.46 146.80

The device is brand new, and can write at speeds more than 27 MB/s sustained.
This makes me think the internal USB-port is somehow flaky.
There are no errors in dmesg or tail -f /var/log/syslog (such as resetting port or similar). And I get no errors on the command line either (i.e. the writes complete with no error but extremely slowly).
What is the cause for this extremely slow and varying speed?
Good port:
[ 6731.885230] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 6732.047642] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 1.10
[ 6732.047662] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6732.047670] usb 1-4: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[ 6732.047676] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 6732.047681] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 408D5C15CB92E7A1E9110821
[ 6732.048973] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0951 ProdID=1666 Rev= 1.10
S:  Manufacturer=Kingston
S:  Product=DataTraveler 3.0
S:  SerialNumber=408D5C15CB92E7A1E9110821
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=300mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms

Bad port:
[    2.704037] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 1.10
[    2.704101] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.704145] usb 2-3: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[    2.704186] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Kingston
[    2.704226] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: B42E99B07A9FE7A1E90F0632
[    4.383332] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    4.400487] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0951 ProdID=1666 Rev= 1.10
S:  Manufacturer=Kingston
S:  Product=DataTraveler 3.0
S:  SerialNumber=B42E99B07A9FE7A1E90F0632
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=300mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2/50
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2/50
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 413c:2111 Dell Computer Corp. Dell USB Wired Entry Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub


A general comment: NAS are often bad on USB (and bad hardware design). In fact your NAS provides just USB 2.0 (USB 3.0 was released on 2008!). It shows how little care they have about USB (and so cheap solutions, probably old chips, and you may imagine not also not well engineered: it is not an important part). I do not have specific info (how it is connected to the bus, which bus, how many lines, how to interrupts, etc.). A computer and network from NAS is probably significant faster (but more inconvenient)
